# Convert Python binary data to R using rpy2

Tags: python, r, rpy2

My goal is to get bytes data from Python to R to `unserialize` in R. The following code provides the test

```
import rpy2.robjects as ro
rcode = 'serialize(iris, NULL)'
r_res = ro.r(rcode)
print(type(r_res[0]))
# <class 'bytes'>

# Works up to here, not sure what how to get the 'bytes' type back into R

# Got 24 from the Rinternals.h file where it indicates RAWSXP
rawsxp_rinternals = 24
r_vec = ro.SexpVector(r_res[0], rawsxp_rinternals)
```

This yields the following error:

```
Error while converting to Bytes element 0.
```

Ideally I would want to achieve the following

1. get the raw data back into R
2. unserialize the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R's `serialize()` is returning a list of byte vectors. This is the input expected by `unserialize()`. The following will "just work":

```
ro.r('unserialize')(r_res)
```

Otherwise, building an rpy2 `Vector` (for an R `RAWSXP` vector) can be achieved like for other vectors:

```
>>> ro.rinterface.str_typeint(r_res.typeof)
'RAWSXP'
>>> r_res2 = ro.vectors.Vector(r_res)
>>> ro.rinterface.str_typeint(r_res2.typeof)
'RAWSXP'
>>> r_res3 = ro.vectors.Vector([r_res[0]])
>>> ro.rinterface.str_typeint(r_res3.typeof)
'RAWSXP'
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the following works for me:

R code:

```
library(stringi)

foo <- function(binary_data) {
    typeof(binary_data) # raw
    # to decode use rawToChar if encoding is utf-8
    # or stri_conv(binary_data, "from_encoding", "to_encoding"), from the lib stringi
    stri_conv(binary_data, "utf8") # "my text"
}
```

Python code:

```
import rpy2.robjects as ro

text = "my text"
binary = text.encode("utf8")

r_raw_vector = ro.rinterface.ByteSexpVector(binary)
ro.r.foo(data=r_raw_vector)
```